# is it possible have ruby read 12:34 as a integer?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working with a script that only takes integer values. I'm reading from a CSV with a timestamp example of 12:34. Is there a way I get ruby to read it as an integer?

Comment: Can you do any sort of pre-processing? or on-the-fly processing? If not, Ruby will read it in as 12. And I don't really understand the limitation. If you're reading in a CSV file, I would think all values are Strings by default and would have to be converted into Integers.

Comment: Have you tried anything? What is your desired outcome?. `12` or `1234` or `12.34` or `[12,34]`

Comment: What integer would it supposed to be interpreted as?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are dealing with a Time object. If so:

```
str = Time.now.to_s[/\d\d:\d\d:\d\d/]
 => "19:04:53" 

str.gsub(":", "").to_i
 => 190453
```

If it's a string just start with the sub:

```
"12:34".sub(":", "").to_i
 => 1234
```